# Starting a process with a shell, possible injection detected, security issue

Tags: python-2.7, security, bandit-python

Using`bandit` for checking the code for vulnerability issues.

https://docs.openstack.org/bandit/1.4.0/plugins/start_process_with_a_shell.html

How to go about resolving this? Is there an alternative to using `commands` library( i.e `commands.getoutput`)? Please advise.

( python 2.7)
New to this security field, kindly update the tags if these aren't appropriate.

Here it says, https://github.com/openstack/bandit/blob/master/bandit/plugins/injection_shell.py#L62

commands.getoutput is vulnerable, but doesn't suggest a replacement! Ugh!

Could sombebody please recommend a solution to this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I have found is , marking tests which you  know for sure to be false flags with the `--no-sec` flag. This will omit that particular test from bandit's checks/